# Good references to understand sub-Riemannian geometry and Heisenberg groups

Tags: sub-riemannian-geometry, heisenberg-groups, learning-roadmap

I'm looking for books and articles to understand a little about the Heisenberg group and sub-Riemannian geometry, specifically why the Heisenberg group is an example of a sub-Riemannian manifold, and what are the implications of this, including the definition of the sub-Laplacian. I actually need introductory material, as I still don't really understand the difference between Riemannian geometry and sub-Riemannian geometry, as unfortunately I only found materials with very disconnected information.

Comment: have you checked out the references in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Riemannian_manifold ? these include lecture notes...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker These Wikipedia references are books in which each chapter is an article, so they are not introductory material. But I leave here a link to good material that can help a layman like me to study https://people.sissa.it/~agrachev/agrachev_files/ABB-final-SRnotes.pdf

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461263/good-references-to-understand-sub-riemannian-geometry-and-heisenberg-groups#comment1196471_461263), it is acceptable to answer your own questions, so, if these notes answer your question, then you should post them as an answer.